# In C why the parameter passed to a void function is compiled while it has to throw an error

Tags: c, function, declaration

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(z)
{
    printf("%d",z);
}
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    fun(a);
}
```

This is giving output as 5. Shouldn't it give an error - **undeclared variable z** ?

Is this a compiler optimization ?

Comment: Ancient C has implicit `int` type.

Comment: `z` is not 'not declared'. It is a parameter of the function (and its type is implicitly `int`).

Comment: Never ever write such code! Get a C book about **modern** C (which started 17 years ago with C99). And `z` apparently **is** declared - the prehistoric way. You compiler should warn. If not: **always** enable at least the recommended warnings and pay heed to them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a compiler optimization, it is a compliance with an ancient C convention that allowed you to skip variable and parameter types when the desired type is `int`. This convention pre-dates the ANSI standard, and should be avoided even if your compiler is fine with such code.

You will get a warning if you tell the compiler that you want your code to comply with one of more modern standards, say, C99 or C11. The flag is compiler-dependent. If you are using `gcc`, add

```
-std=c99
```

flag to see the warning.